# Unable to input string values when taking multiple input in one line (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiple-input

**Using the code below:**

```
print("Welcome to band name generator!!")
city,pet = input("What is the name of the city you grew up in?\t") + input ("\nWhat is the name of your first pet?\t")
print("\n\t Your band name can be " + city + " "+ pet + "!!")
```

I can input single variable (eg - a/b/c or 1/2/3) and the program works fine but it we input string values or words(eg- Canada,New_york), I get the following error -
**too many values to unpack (expected 2)**

How can I resolve this while keeping input in one line?

Comment: You are assigning Canada,New_york to a single value city. Hence the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace the `+` with a `,` since the `+` is going to concatenate your inputs into one string.

```
city, pet = input("What is the name of the city you grew up in?\t"), input ("\nWhat is the name of your first pet?\t")
```

Whenever you get the `too many values to unpack` Error, make sure that the number of variables on the left side matches the number of values on the right side.

Answer (score 1):

Use the split function,it helps in getting a multiple inputs from user. It breaks the given input by the specified separator. If a separator is not provided then any white space is a separator.

```
print("Welcome to band name generator!!")
city,pet = input("Enter the city and pet name  ").split()
print("\n\t Your band name can be " + city + " "+ pet + "!!")
```